# How to change ListView item color dynamically?

Tags: listview, data-binding, uwp, prism

I'm trying to change color of some ListView elements using data binding.
For example, I have a list of Questions.

[image]

And I need to highlight already answered questions

[image]

I need to highlight answered Question immediately after user makes a choice.
There is my list item DataTemplate:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="QuestionListDataTemplate">
            <Border Padding="5" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Gray" Background="Transparent">
            <TextBlock FontSize="24" 
                       x:Name="QuestionListDataTemplateText"
                       Foreground="{Binding Color}">
                <Run x:Uid="QuestionsPage/QuestionNumber"/>
                <Run Text="{Binding QuestionNumber}"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
```

There is a `Question` model:

```
public class Question : TemplateQuestion
{
    public string PollId { get; set; }
    public string SelectedAnswerId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Ignore]
    public SolidColorBrush Color { get; set; }

    [Ignore]
    public bool Answered { get; set; }

    [Ignore]
    public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }

    [Ignore]
    public int QuestionNumber { get; set; }
}
```

I tried also to change color using `DataTemplateSelector` and `IValueConverter`, but it doesn't work.

Is there a way to selectively change style of `ListView` items?

Comment: Change `public SolidColorBrush Color {get;set;}` to **DependencyProperty**, change binding mode to **OneWay**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a way to do that.

You should make the question inherit INotifyPropertyChanged that can notify the xaml when the property changed.

For you cant use convert that is the Xaml dont know the property update. I write the code below.

```
public class Question : TemplateQuestion, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string PollId { get; set; }
    public string SelectedAnswerId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public SolidColorBrush Color
    {
        get { return _color; }
        set
        {
            _color = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public bool Answered { get; set; }

    public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }

    public int QuestionNumber { get; set; }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    private SolidColorBrush _color;
}
```

Comment: This worked! But there is a question. What is ```[NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]```? I not found it anywhere. Just removed this line and code worked well without it too. Maybe this not for UWP? Or not for Prism? Or it is presented only in ```ViewModelBase``` class?
 Any explanations?

Comment: @ashchuk It's Resharper attribute from [Annotations](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp80/Code_Analysis__Code_Annotations.html)